# zigbee seies 2 (xbee model ) , zigbee + microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, zigbee

Does a zigbee series 2 ( xbee ) module have a inbuilt microcontroller? If yes, is it possible to reprogram that microcontroller? If not, then is it possible to use an external  microcontroller.

Comment: I don't know the particulars, or exactly what you are talking about, but the TI chips that I have looked at, and are the heart of most hobbyist zigbee modules, have a 8051 ip core that you would program over jtag

Comment: why is that , I am getting negative comments ?

Comment: @hanumesh - I don't know why you are getting downvoted. It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: how to communicate between xbee S2 and
microcontroller without using any software???,
(I just want to use my xbee s2,hyperterminal and
controller)
pls reply me asap…

Comment: @Prasad if you have a question, please click on the button "Ask question" in the top right corner. For the best results, please write it as clear and complete as possible.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52849/use-xbee-io-with-out-microcontroller

Answer (score 3):

The XBee devices do have built-in microcontrollers.

However, Digi does not make a SDK, or the resources required to compile your own firmware image available for the Series-2 XBees.

You could probably *theoretically* reverse-engineer the modules, and write your own firmware for them. However, judging from the fact that you're asking this question, I think that's a bit over your head at the moment.

Comment: @thank you !!.  I have a two working xbee series 2  modules, one i have set-up as co-ordinator and other as end device using x-CTU tool . Now , i have to connect a sensor to one of the xbee module and transmitt data via zigbee n/w and show the transmission .

Comment: Unless your sensor has an analog output (and you're willing to live with the crap 10-bit resolution of the XBee ADCs), it sounds like you'll need an additional MCU at each end.

Comment: 1 )http://answers.oreilly.com/uploads/monthly_02_2011/post-3071-129727201554.png

Comment: 2) http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2467-how-to-use-direct-input-and-output-on-an-xbee-radio/

Comment: these two links say that it has analog inputs? I am i right

Comment: @hanumesh - Please re-read the comment I left above: Yes, the XBees have (rather crappy) 10 bit ADCs. If that's good enough for your application, it may work.

Comment: Yeah , it supports analog inputs .

Comment: @ Connor Wolf - I am using zigbee operator tool to setup zigbee network ( http://www.zigbeeoperator.com/index.html ).The co-ordinator is connected to pc ( windows os ) via RS232. Everything works fine but, how do i change the status of end device in a zigbee n/w . Is that,the end device should be connected to some kind of sensors and send information to co-ordinator